# SendGrid WebHook call

Tags: sendgrid

SendGrid WebHook returns data packed in an object which has a number of properties.
One of them is "smtp-id" which appears to be email message id.
My question is, if an email gets deferred and a "new" message is constructed this "new" email has new email message id. Is there a property on WebHook return call object which returns the original email message id?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.